# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT and DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tb1 table like this :

```
name   email               link
john   myemail@gmail.com   google
john   myemail@gmail.com   facebook
john   myemail2@gmail.com  twitter
....
....
and more
```

When I call data with query looks like

```
SELECT name, email, group_concat(DISTINCT link SEPARATOR '/') as source
FROM tb1
group by email
```

And result Like this :

```
NAME    EMAIL               SOURCE
john    myemail2@gmail.com  twitter
john    myemail@gmail.com   facebook/google
....
....
and more
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e9a7f/4/0)

I want make result looks like :

```
NAME    EMAIL               SOURCE 1       SOURCE 2
john    myemail2@gmail.com  twitter
john    myemail@gmail.com   facebook       google
```

It's possible to make result only with query?

Note : I want to make dynamic column source 1, 2, 3 ...., n

Comment: That's a variation pivot table  (In theory, Source 1, Source 2.... can continue to Source X based on X number of distinct Source values, right?)  If so, you should search for "mysql pivot table", there are some great (albeit non-trivial) articles

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: thanks @AgRizzo for ref, I will read about mysql pivot table. This question can hold. I will update my question when I stuck with mysql pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is, **don't do it!**

What you want to do is called pivoting. In MySQL this is usually done with one hell of a

```
....
aggregate_function(case when ...),
aggregate_function(case when ...),
aggregate_function(case when ...),
...
```

block. But since you don't know all your sources, you'd have to write a procedure to dynamically build the statement for you and execute it. And even then you'd end up with a table structure like

```
NAME    EMAIL               twitter     facebook    google
----------------------------------------------------------
john    myemail2@gmail.com  yes         no          no
john    myemail@gmail.com   no          yes         yes
```

So, how would the programmers of your application know how the columns are named?

To avoid this you'd have to do again one hell of a programming in your stored procedure to put the row values of each email into one column. Then how would you determine, which row gets into which column? What if facebook appears in one row in column source1 and in another row in column source2? And in your application you'd have to test or otherwise determine how much columns there are actually, or can each user/email only have 2 sources?

To sum things up, a result like this

```
name   email               link
john   myemail@gmail.com   google
john   myemail@gmail.com   facebook
john   myemail2@gmail.com  twitter
```

is perfectly fine and it's up to the application developers to deal with it. And it's much, much easier to do so for them than for the database guy in your team.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't since with MySQL you can not create dynamically additional column... (this is more an olap stuff or wich allow such functionality called pivot table)

Comment: he never mentioned dinamic

Comment: @AdrianBR if its not dynamic then my answer can work, but asker need to verify it.

Answer (score 1):

It can work for this case, but its not a dynamic query and can work only if there are maximum of 2 link present for same email.

```
SELECT `name`, email, 
substring_index(group_concat(DISTINCT link SEPARATOR '/'),'/',1) as source_1,
if(group_concat(DISTINCT link SEPARATOR '/') like '%/%',
substring_index(group_concat(DISTINCT link SEPARATOR '/'),'/',-1),'') as source_2
FROM test2 group by email
```

If you know the exact number of possibility of links present per email then the same query can be modify accordingly.